# How to keep previous offset in rotate animation after dragging a same object with Kinetic?

Tags: javascript, kineticjs

could any one show my how to drag my object but still keep its previous offset in rotate animation. I try so many times but still not find the solution. When i drag an object, it didn't rotate in orbit :( .

Here is my code

#### HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
  <body>
    <div id="container"></div>
    <script src="http://d3lp1msu2r81bx.cloudfront.net/kjs/js/lib/kinetic-v5.0.2.min.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

#### CSS

```
  body {
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
  }
  canvas {
    border: 1px solid #9C9898;
  }
```

### JS

```
 window.onload = function() {
        var stage = new Kinetic.Stage({
          container: 'container',
          width: 500,
          height: 500
        });
        var layer = new Kinetic.Layer(),
            cx = stage.getWidth() / 2,
            cy = stage.getWidth() / 2;


        var bigCircle = new Kinetic.Circle({
                  x: cx ,
                  y: cy,
         radius: 200,
                  stroke: 'lightgray',
                  strokeWidth: 8,
                });


        /*
         * move center point outside of the rectangle
         * with offset
         */
        var smallCirlce = new Kinetic.Circle({
          x: cx,
          y: cy,
          radius: 20,
          fill:'rgb(0,102,204)',
          strokeWidth: 4,
          offset: {x:getRandom(-150,150), y:getRandom(-150,150)}
        });

function getRandom(minNum, maxNum){
return Math.random() * (maxNum - minNum) + minNum;
};

        layer.add(bigCircle);
layer.add(smallCirlce);
        stage.add(layer);

        // one revolution per 4 seconds
        var angularSpeed = 360 / 4;
        var anim = new Kinetic.Animation(function(frame) {
          var angleDiff = frame.timeDiff * angularSpeed / 1000;
          smallCirlce.rotate(angleDiff);
        }, layer);

        anim.start();
      };
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is what you are after. What I took from your description was that you want to be able to drag the blue ball and have it continue orbiting around its initial point but at a greater radius.

Firstly, here is a fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/Paul_Smith/206meq0a/

What this solution does is on mousedown, convert the circle's position, offset and rotation into a single coordinate representing the actual position of the circle in space.

It then allows you to drag the circle, and resets its offset to the new one by subtracting its actual position from its original position.

Probably not the best solution out there but I am not a very math oriented programmer :)

The important functions are as below:

```
//Calculate an angle in radians given degrees
function degreesToRadians(degrees) {
    return degrees * Math.PI / 180;
}

//Transform a coordinate by way of a rotation in degrees.
//Rotated about { x: 0, y: 0 }
function translateCoordinate(coordinate, degrees) {    
    var radians = degreesToRadians(degrees);

    return {
        x: (coordinate.x * Math.cos(radians)) - (coordinate.y * Math.sin(radians)),
        y: (coordinate.x * Math.sin(radians)) + (coordinate.y * Math.cos(radians))
    };
}

smallCircle.on("mousedown", function () {
    var rotation = smallCircle.rotation(),
        offset = smallCircle.offset(),
        position = smallCircle.position(),
        translatedOffset;

    //Calculate how the offset has changed due to the rotation   
    translatedOffset = translateCoordinate(offset, rotation);

    //Set the position to that of the current position - the offset
    smallCircle.position({
        x: position.x - translatedOffset.x,
        y: position.y - translatedOffset.y
    });

    //set the offset to 0 as it has now been added to the position
    smallCircle.offset({
        x: 0,
        y: 0
    });

    //Set the rotation to 0 as it is now part of the position due to the   
    //translation which has taken place
    smallCircle.rotation(0);

    //Reset the drag position
    smallCircle.stopDrag();
    smallCircle.startDrag();
});

smallCircle.on("mouseup", function () {
    var position = smallCircle.position();

    //Calculate the new offset (original position - new position)
    smallCircle.offset({
        x: cx - position.x,
        y: cy - position.y
    });

    //Set the position back to the original position
    smallCircle.position({
        x: cx,
        y: cy
    });
});
```

Hope this helps